# Remove JSON block based on a condition

Tags: python, json, conditional-statements

I am trying to remove a block based on key - value in json file in python. A snippet of the JSON file is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "endTime" : "2021-01-21 07:44",
    "artistName" : "Edward Sharpe & The Magnetic Zeros",
    "trackName" : "Home",
    "msPlayed" : 241536
  },
  {
    "endTime" : "2021-01-21 08:48",
    "artistName" : "t.A.T.u.",
    "trackName" : "All The Things She Said",
    "msPlayed" : 186644
  },
  ...
]
```

What I can't do is remove the `"entry"` between 2 `{ }` if `msPlayed` is `< 30000` mS. Any suggestions?

Edit: what I tried so far is

```
import json

obj  = json.load(open("StreamingHistory0.json", encoding= 'utf-8' ))

# Iterate through the objects in the JSON and pop (remove)
# the obj once we find it.
for i in range(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["msPlayed"] < 29999:
        obj.pop(i)
        break

# Output the updated file with pretty JSON
open("updated-file.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How about creating a new list and adding all the dicts which don't satisfy the condition?

Comment: load the json, iterate over list and filter out the elements you don't want to keep.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Edit your question to include all the relevant information. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: Also, I suggest you check https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/4046632

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single line with **list comprehension** should do the trick for you. **See** https://rextester.com/YNAO67705

```
expected = [element for element in data if element['msPlayed'] < 30000 ]
```

**Full Code:**

```
import json
data  = json.load(open("StreamingHistory0.json", encoding= 'utf-8' ))

# Iterate through the objects in the JSON and filter                     
expected = [element for element in data if element['msPlayed'] < 30000 ]

# Output the updated file with pretty JSON                                      
open("updated-file.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(expected, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)
```

Comment: yes, but if i load the json from disk... how could i solve this?

Comment: Added full working code that reads from disk, filter and write back to disk on another file.